# NSURLSessionDownloadTask progress callback is not smoothly?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, asihttprequest, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I download a file by NSURLSessionDownloadTask in foreground, and I need to show the current download speed in the UI,

but I found that the delegate method:`URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` is not be called smoothly:
[image]

so I can show the accurate current download speed.

I make sure this is not caused by the server. when I download the same file via ASIHTTPRequest, it's OK, the progress block was called smoothly.

Anyone knows WHY? Thanks!

## UPDATE #0:

The delegate method's implementation:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
      didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
    _totalReceived += bytesWritten;
    NSLog(@"receive: %8.2f KB, total receive: %8.2f KB", bytesWritten / 1024.f,  _totalReceived / 1024.f);
    CFTimeInterval now = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    if (_lastDataReceiveAt > 0.f) {
        CFTimeInterval delta = now - _lastDataReceiveAt;
        NSLog(@"downloadtask: %p, speed: %8.2f KB/s; avg: %8.2f KB/s; delta time: %3.2fs",
              downloadTask,
              bytesWritten / 1024 / delta, _totalReceived / 1024 / (now - _beginsAt),
              delta);
    }
    _lastDataReceiveAt = now;

    //NSLog(@"downloading ... %.2f%%", totalBytesWritten * 100.f / totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}
```

## UPDATE #1:

Hi, @Rob, Here is my session installation code:

```
- (NSURLSession *)sessionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    if (identifier == nil) {
        NSString *bundleId = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
        identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:///Downloader#%ld", bundleId, time(NULL)];
    }

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    //config.protocolClasses = @[ASIURLProtocol.class];
    return [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
}
```

And, the download task initialize:

```
_session = [self sessionWithIdentifier:nil];
NSURL *url = ...;
_task = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:url];
[_task resume];

CFTimeInterval now = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
_beginsAt = now;
_lastDataReceiveAt = now;
_totalReceived = 0;
```

Comment: I tested a few obvious possibilities (the session's queue's priority; concurrent queue v serial queue; download task v data task; making sure app had reached quiescence; etc.) and nothing jumped out at me. There's just some episodic latency of the calls with `URLSession`. If ASIHTTPRequest didn't suffer from this, it may just be a difference between `URLSession` and whatever ASIHTTPRequest used. I'd simply suggest sticking with `URLSession` and using some trailing average or something like that, rather than ever relying on one data point to calculate speed.

Comment: While we see some episodic latency in the `NSURLSession` delegate methods, it's generally measured in milliseconds, not 10 seconds (!). I notice that you're using the main queue for your delegate's queue, and if you ever block the main thread, you could see the sort of behavior you describe. I'd suggest changing the queue parameter to `nil` and see if this 10 second latency goes away. If so, though, you really should go back and identify what's blocking the main thread, as it should never be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by smoothly here? That they are not called at equal time intervals? This is expected.

All you need to do is keep track of the start time and in the call back calculate the speed from the elapsed time and the data received.

If this is not the issue, please provide more code, perhaps the delegate method implementation and what produces these logs. Maybe also what you would like the logs to be?

Comment: Or you could just use the size of data received in the most recent call, and the time elapsed since the last call, and use that to determine the speed. That would solve this issue.

Comment: Isn't that what he's doing? The problem is that there is a tiny bit of latency in some of the progress updates, so when he looks at just the last data point, it looks like the speed is fluctuating wildly. I'm suggesting something in between "look at last data point" and "average all data points"...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I understand. You probably want to have a play with what works best for your interface but a few ideas... You could try a simple sliding window style and look at the last X chunks and average over those. Or, a better idea would be to calculate a weighted average over all of the chunks. You could assign a lower weighting to the less recent chunks, so that you are still getting a representative value, but better taking into account the recency for the change in speed.

Comment: @Rob  Yes, That's what I want to do.  But the delegate method not be called "smoothly",   a batch of data is coming in a short time, and then, after a long time(10 sec?),  the next batch of data is arrive in a short time. So the speed wave shape suddenly up and then slowly coming down and suddenly up again, periodically.

Comment: @AlexLee - 10 seconds is a bit extreme, but your code shows us your calculation of speed at each call of `didWriteData`, and I'm suggesting that you calculate the speed at each call, but then average, say, the last 5 or 6 in a trailing average, to keep it focused on recent speed, but not rely solely on the last call.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, this is just a demo, in my project I calculate the speed by recording the bytes received in the last 5 seconds, and then average. But the results like this: 140k ... 0k ... 200k ... 0k ... 80k ... 0k ... 100k ...

Comment: @AlexLee - if your episodic latency is 10 seconds, then averaging the updates from the last 5 seconds clearly won't work. The interval at which you calculate average speeds must exceed the max latency delays you're seeing. Or, better, average the last _x_ updates rather than using a fixed period of time. But you should solve the 10 second latency problem (possibly a result of the main queue being periodically blocked), because that is not normal.